# QAudioProbe не работает с source QMediaPlayer в windows

Tags: qt

```
    if(probe->setSource(player))
    {
        qDebug() << "source set ok";

    }
    else
    {
         qDebug() << "source not set";
    }
```

возвращает "source not set" в Windows.

это проблемный кусок кода, весь проект прекрасно работает в  linux!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема [аналогична](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html) `QVideoProbe`:

> The WMF plugin in Qt does not currently provide a camera backend.
>   Instead, limited support for camera features is provided by the
>   DirectShow plugin. Basic features such as displaying a viewfinder and
>   capturing a still image are supported, however, majority of camera
>   controls are not implemented.
>
> Video recording is currently not supported. Additionally, the
>   DirectShow plugin does not support any low-level video functionality
>   such as monitoring video frames being played or recorded using
>   QVideoProbe or related classes.

Вероятно, что давно нет ведущего разработчика (или вообще никто не хочет этим заниматься) плагинов по направлению QtMultimedia. Реализовано множество обёрток-контролов, предоставляющих унифицированные методы по управлению мультимедиа устройствами, а вот платформозависимый код давно уже не претерпевает каких-либо изменений. С линуксом попроще оказалось, так как бекенд на gstreamer основан и соответственно функционал поддержки устройств сам по себе отчасти обновляется. А с виндовсом хуже - недописали полностью под WMF, а затем и вовсе оставили без внимания.

Comment: а есть какие то альтернативы чтоб можно было стрим слушать/писать/визуализировать.?

Comment: @JohnDoe , например, ffmpeg. Кроссплатформенный, многофункциональный. Единственное, он на С и довольно сложен в изучении. Вообще, мультимедиа бекенды в Qt построены в виде плагинов. Может разрабы так и задумывали, что кому что надо, тот ту поддержку платформозависимого кода и реализует, а мы всё ждём у моря погоды.

Comment: да вот решил забить на QMedia , сейчас разбираюсь с bass'ом, он хотя бы нормально документирован.

Comment: использовал Bass library, с ним все отлично работает